# When did update-apt-xapian-index last run?

Tags: apt, indexing

How do I find out when `update-apt-xapian-index` last ran? Is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you need is `axi-cache info`. You can consult its [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/axi-cache.1.html) or built-in help.

But the main problem that it is broken out the box on 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS and newer versions because of [bug 1612948](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1612948). Instead of desired output it returns error message:

```
$ axi-cache 
No module named 'ConfigParser': only help functions are implemented, for the sake of help2man
```

Citing Brian Murray from [comment on bug 1760608](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-xapian-index/+bug/1760608/comments/4)

> Brian Murray (brian-murray) wrote on 2018-04-06:  #4
>
> The correct solution is to modify the import in axi-info to "from ConfigParser" to "from configparser". If someone created a debdiff I'd be happy to sponsor it.

so we can use my original proposal from [comment on bug 1612948](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-xapian-index/+bug/1612948/comments/5)

```
sudo sed -i 's/from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser/from configparser import RawConfigParser/' /usr/bin/axi-cache
```

---

After manual patching it will work (output from 16.04 LTS):

```
$ axi-cache --help
Usage: axi-cache [options] command [args]

Query the Apt Xapian index.

Commands:
...
     axi-cache info      print information about the apt-xapian-index environment
...


$ axi-cache info
Main data directory: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index
Update timestamp: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/update-timestamp (last updated: Fri Jun 15 01:33:15 2018)
Index location: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/index (pointing to /var/cache/apt-xapian-index/index.1)
Documentation of index contents: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/README
Documentation of available prefixes: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/prefixes
Documentation of available values: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/values
Plugin directory: /usr/share/apt-xapian-index/plugins
Plugin status:
  aliases         enabled, up to date (105 days, 3:48:59 older than index)
  app-install     enabled, up to date (1008 days, 14:58:48 older than index)
  apttags         enabled, needs indexing (9 days, 10:54:14.379738 newer than index)
  cataloged_time  enabled, needs indexing (9 days, 10:54:14.379738 newer than index)
  debtags         disabled
  descriptions    enabled, needs indexing (9 days, 10:54:14.379738 newer than index)
  relations       enabled, needs indexing (9 days, 10:54:14.379738 newer than index)
  sections        enabled, needs indexing (9 days, 10:54:14.379738 newer than index)
  sizes           enabled, needs indexing (9 days, 10:54:14.379738 newer than index)
  template        enabled, up to date
  translated-desc enabled, up to date (0:00:00 older than index)
Values:
  Value         Code Provided by
  app-popcon       3 app-install
  catalogedtime    4 cataloged_time
  installedsize    1 sizes
  packagesize      2 sizes
  version          0 update-apt-xapian-index
Data sources:
  Source                                           Description                                     Used by
  /usr/share/apt-xapian-index/aliases/popular-apps Aliases expanding names of popular applications aliases
  /usr/share/app-install/desktop/                  .desktop files provided by app-install-data     app-install
  /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin                      APT index                                       apttags, descriptions, relations, sections, sizes
  /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p      first-seen information for every package        cataloged_time
```

So we need reply and/or action from Ubuntu developers to have these fixes applied.

Comment: Thank you! `Update timestamp: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/update-timestamp (last updated: Sun Jun 24 07:06:13 2018)`. I marked the bug "affects me too".

Comment: Interesting: "The Canonical Ubuntu Foundations team has made a decision that we won't be working on this particular bug given that it is about a package in universe." from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-xapian-index/+bug/1612948/comments/27). And so your fix is needed in 19.10 as well!

Comment: Although I'm very tempted to get rid of *apt-xapian-index* altogether since I don't need its indexing services.

Comment: Removing this package will disable full-feature search in Synaptic and Muon. I'll check it again to compare with upstream Debian variant.

Comment: That is true but I don't use either Muon or Synaptic's full-feature search. (I mostly don't use GUI software package managers.)

Comment: Most of the time me too, but from newbie point of view this is expected and very useful feature :)