# When is update-apt-xapian-index scheduled to run?

Tags: cron, indexing

OS: Kubuntu 18.04.3

```
$ update-apt-xapian-index --version
update-apt-xapian-index 0.47
$
```

*/etc/cron.weekly* has *apt-xapian-index*. None of the other *cron*-related folders in */etc* have *apt-xapian-index* or something similar.

Based on the location of *apt-xapian-index*, I'd expect it to run once a week.

However, running `axi-cache info` (after incorporating the workaround described by N0rbert [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049264/248158)) leads me to believe it's running more frequently than that. Here's the relevant output over the last few days:

```
Update timestamp: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/update-timestamp (last updated: Fri Sep 27 14:21:48 2019)
Update timestamp: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/update-timestamp (last updated: Sun Sep 29 06:34:46 2019)
Update timestamp: /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/update-timestamp (last updated: Mon Sep 30 06:31:35 2019)
```

Why is that? How does *update-apt-xapian-index* know when and how often to run instead of running just once a week?

---

Edit: I should add that I exclusively use `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`. I don't use package managers such as *muon* or *synaptic* or any software center which may cause *update-apt-xapian-index* to run in order to updates their datbases or internal indexes.

---

```
$ systemctl list-timers --all
NEXT                         LEFT        LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Mon 2019-09-30 18:02:59 IST  8min left   Mon 2019-09-30 17:03:42 IST  50min ago    anacron.timer                anacron.service
Tue 2019-10-01 03:29:28 IST  9h left     Mon 2019-09-30 06:27:35 IST  11h ago      apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Tue 2019-10-01 05:36:56 IST  11h left    Mon 2019-09-30 12:36:49 IST  5h 17min ago motd-news.timer              motd-news.service
Tue 2019-10-01 06:17:32 IST  12h left    Mon 2019-09-30 06:27:35 IST  11h ago      apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
Tue 2019-10-01 06:42:49 IST  12h left    Mon 2019-09-30 06:42:49 IST  11h ago      systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Mon 2019-10-07 00:00:00 IST  6 days left Mon 2019-09-30 06:27:35 IST  11h ago      fstrim.timer                 fstrim.service
n/a                          n/a         Mon 2019-09-30 06:28:35 IST  11h ago      ureadahead-stop.timer        ureadahead-stop.service

7 timers listed.
$
```

Comment: Systemd timers?  `systemctl list-timers --all`

Comment: @user535733, I've added the output for my system. So is *apt-daily.timer* or *apt-daily-upgrade.timer* related to `update-apt-xapian-index`? But then what is the meaning of having `update-apt-xapian-index` in */etc/cron.weekly*?